# How to show an alertview on receiving push notifications when app is not launched?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am new to iOS development. I want to show an alertview on receiving a push notification while app is inactive.

Apple says that push notification can be presented in form of alert message or they can badge the application icon.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

I am using [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) to send push notifications. But notifications are seen in notification center only. What should I do to show it on alertview?

I know we can write a code to show alertview like

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"test title" message:@"test message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alert show];

}
```

But this code is executed after I tap notification and app launches. I want to show `alertview` as soon as device receives a push notification.

One more question, does Apple support any way to execute a code on receiving push notification though app is not launched?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Possible with the UIAlertView . You can go through the `UILocalNotification` to achieve your task .

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    notifaication = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notifaication.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    notifaication.alertBody = // Set the Body
    notifaication.alertAction =// @"Show me";
    backupAlarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
}
```

For More info [over_Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Comment: Do note that application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: is called when a push notification comes while your app is in the foreground OR if the user chooses to interact with the notification.